# mvc uppercase Model vs lowercase model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on a MVC 5 project, very new to MVC.  I noticed this line in the code:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ContractorId, Model.Contractors)
```

the directive on the top of the page is:

```
@model Project.Models.ContractViewModel
```

The ContractViewModel class does have a Contractors object in it.

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Contractors
```

I'm just a little confused on the capital M (Model.Contractors), does Model always refer to the object passed in the @model?  Then what is the difference between using Model.Contractors and model.Contractors?

Comment: First line is using model as lambda expression only. `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ContractorId, Model.Contractors)` even `@Html.DropDownListFor(myself => myself.ContractorId, Model.Contractors)`  are also correct.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**Model** actually represents an instance of the class that is your **model** and model is an alias for lambda expression.

When you write `@Model` in your view you are using the object of `ContractViewModel` which is passed from Controller action, if it is not passed from View it can be null and accessing any property of Model can throw **Null Reference Exception** and writing `Model.Contractors` you basically mean `ContractViewModel.Contractors`

and when you write a html helper you need to write an alias for it, its not mandatory to write `model` you can write anything.

for example:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=> m.ContractorId, Model.Contractors)
```

It is just an alias to access the model properties inside **Html Helper**.

When you write `@model Project.Models.ContractViewModel` at the top of View that is a different thing, in this case we are defining the model of view that it will take instance of `Project.Models.ContractViewModel` , actually our view is now strongly typed to instance of class `Project.Models.ContractViewModel`.