# ASP.NET MVC ViewModel to view issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i don't really have a problem with my code just a question I like someone to resolve, (as I am likely doing it wrong)

I have a viewmodel that contains models + SelectLists that I'm passing into a view

```
public class VmTheViewModel
{
    public int Car_ID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetCars { get; set; }
    public int Parent_ID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetParents { get; set; }
    public T class1 { get; set; }
    public T class2 { get; set; }

}
```

So on top of the view page I include

```
@model VmTheViewModel
```

So now, I bind a `HTML.DropDownListFor` with one of my `SelectListItem`s

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Car_ID, Model.GetCars)
```

However, if I want to bind a property from class1 to a `HTML.TextBoxFor` using model, it causes an error

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.class1.color)

// ERROR: cannot be inferred from the usage. 
// Try specifying the type arguments explicitly
```

But this works,

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.class1.color)
```

I just like to know why I couldnt use model.class1.color as its the same object (viewmodel) as in the DropDownListFor? why do I need to reference a new type? (x =>)

Cheers

Comment: see this will help you understand things:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23293886/mvc-uppercase-model-vs-lowercase-model/23293926

Comment: Perfect thanks - hate it when the answer is shorter then the question!