# Razor Html.Raw Cannot Present ViewModel Data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I can do this in a view:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m=> m.Customer.EmailAddress)
```

but can't do this:

```
@Html.Raw(m=> m.Customer.EmailAddress)
```

get

> cannot resolve method 'Raw lambda expression'...

and

> cannot resolve symbol 'Customer'

This is a strongly typed view bound to a ViewModel.

I need to place an unencoded version of the model's email address into a hidden field for a payment gateway. I'm surprised this is an issue (new to MVC).

I've tried just using  `@Html.Raw(model.EmailAddress)` without luck. I know I'm doing something very stupid. Please put me out of my misery!

Comment: You need to unspderstand **model vs Model** see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23293886/mvc-uppercase-model-vs-lowercase-model

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Html.Raw(Model.Customer.EmailAddress)
```

Comment: What a total idiot I am. Thank you. I know it was something stupid!