# MVC 4 what's the difference between model and Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I am almost two years without coding in C# so much my knowledge is lost.
I am working in a project which I found that I can not use model to do some databinding things in the views. In Mvc 4+, is it changing `@model [type]` to `WebPage.Model`? I am only familiar with Mvc3-. If sample project given, I would appreciate that.

Comment: Do you mean as used in a view (and with Razor code)?

Comment: yes,in mvc4+,remove @model?

Comment: Don't remove `@model yourClass`. That defines the model used in the view, and `Model` is then used to access the values of its properties - e.g. `<div>@Model.someProperty</div>`, or in html helpers e.g. `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.someProperty)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [mvc uppercase Model vs lowercase model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23293886/mvc-uppercase-model-vs-lowercase-model)

Answer (score 2):

`@model` is used to "import" a model in the view page while the `@Model` represents the imported model and is where you retrieve its properties.

See the example below:

```
@model MeuExemploMVC.Models.CarrinhoComprasViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Purchase Cart";
}

<h2>@Model.Mensagem
</h2>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Purchase Cart</legend>

    <table>
        <caption>Products</caption>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach (var product in Model.Products) {
            <tr>
                <td>@product.Name</td>
                <td>@product.Price</td>
            </tr>
        }
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Total</strong></td>
                <td>@Model.TotalPrice</td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>

</fieldset>
```

Here you see that `@model` simply imports the Model object to the page while the `@Model` you get actual value from the retrieved model.

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/687061/Multiple-Models-in-a-View-in-ASP-NET-MVC-MVC) is a tutorial from CodeProject which illustrates this difference. Note that a sample code is provided there.