# How can I check if a ViewModel's property is null in a View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

In a `C# MVC 5 View`, how can I check if a `ViewModel's` property is `null`?

Here is my `@model` code:

```
@model DataService.ViewModels.MVC.UserViewModel
```

The `UserViewModel` has a property as follows:

```
public User userParent
{
    get
    {
        return _userParent;
    }
    set
    {
        _userParent = value;
    }
}
```

Here is my `View` code:

```
<dd>
    @if (model.userParent != null)
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => model.userParent.name)
    }
    else
    {

    }
</dd>
```

I am getting the following compiler error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'model' does not exist in the
>   current context

Comment: you probably need to read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23293886/mvc-uppercase-model-vs-lowercase-model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `model` with `Model`. Notice the case of the first letter.

Answer (score 1):

The code should be

```
 @if (Model.userParent != null)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.userParent.name)
}
else
{

}
```

Note the `model` being changed to `Model`