# How to show the value of model in Kendo Custom Editor Template?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I'm using a scheduler of Kendo UI for MVC. I created a Custom Editor Template. It works fine. When click the schedule, it pops a windows and show the info.

I added some properties in the model, the value passed to the editor template. Now, the question is:

How can I show the added properties (just as value, and I do not want to change it) in the editor template popup?

I found that if I use a textbox:

```
@(Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Role, new { @class = "k-textbox" }))
```

It shows a textbox and shows the correct value of Role. However, if I use

```
<div>@(Model.Role)</div>
```

It shows blank, just as the value is NULL.

I actually want to show several added properties as a sentence, i.e. I added Role and UserName and I ant to show something like:

```
UserNameValue has Role of RoleValue
```

Anyone knows how to do it?

I use this as sample in the code:
http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/custom-editor

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is to put this line because the editor template is binded by mvvm

```
<div data-bind="text: Role"></div>
```

[Docs](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/mvvm/bindings/text)

Answer (score 0):

In the code: `model => model.Role` model is just an alias, not an actual object.  You could replace it with `m => m.Role` and it would function the same.

> When you write @Model in your view you are using the object of ContractViewModel which is passed from Controller action, if it is not passed from View it can be null and accessing any property of Model can throw Null Reference Exception and writing Model.Contractors you basically mean ContractViewModel.Contractors

See this post: [mvc uppercase Model vs lowercase model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23293886/mvc-uppercase-model-vs-lowercase-model)