# Can't get model attribute from razor ASP.net - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a form that is fully complete by a model but I cannot get some attributes because I believe that in this moment the model is null. The thing is that when I use `@Model.someattribute` it doesn't work, but with `m => m.cantidadMensajes`, it does. I need to know why it happened and how I have to deal with it?

```
@model SeaConnectionManager.Modelos.EnvioMensajes.InformacionEntity

@{ var previsualizaciones = "";
    if (@Model != null) { 
        previsualizaciones = @Model.vistaPrevia;
   }
}
<div id="Envio" class="overlay">
    <div class="popup">

        <h2 align="center">Información del Env&iacute;o</h2>
        <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
        <div class="content" style="width:100%; margin:auto; padding:10px">
            <center>
                <a id="tabs">
                    <ul>

                        @if (@Model != null) { 
                            if (@Model.cantidadMensajes >= 5)
                            {
                                for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
                                {
                                    <li><a href="#tabs-@i"> @i</a></li>
                                }
                            }
                            else { 
                                for (var i = 1; i <= @Model.cantidadMensajes; i++)
                                {
                                    <li><a href="#tabs-@i"> @i</a></li>
                                }                
                            }
                        }

                    </ul>
                    @previsualizaciones
                </div>

                        <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellspacing="4">

                            <tr>
                                <td width="36%">Cantidad de mensajes</td>
                                <td width="44%">
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.cantidadMensajes, new { @id = "CantidadMensajes", @class = "input-login", @readonly = "readonly" })
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Cantidad de contactos</td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.cantidadContactos, new { @id = "CantidadContactos", @class = "input-login", @readonly = "readonly" })
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Saldo</td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.saldo, new { @id = "Saldo", @class = "input-login", @readonly = "readonly" })
                                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.idTransaccion, new { @id = "idTransaccion" })
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        </table>
            </center><br>
            <center>
                <table width="122" border="0" align="center" cellspacing="10">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="51"><a onclick="EnviarMensajes()" class="boton-para-enviar" style="margin:auto">Aprobar</a></td>
                        <td width="37"><a href="#" class="boton-para-NO-enviar" style="margin:auto">Rechazar</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </center>
```

Changes after following some advices with no luck:

```
   @model SeaConnectionManager.Modelos.EnvioMensajes.InformacionEntity

@{ var previsualizaciones = "";
    if (Model != null) { 
        previsualizaciones = Model.vistaPrevia;
   }
}
<div id="Envio" class="overlay">
    <div class="popup">

        <h2 align="center">Información del Env&iacute;o</h2>
        <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
        <div class="content" style="width:100%; margin:auto; padding:10px">
            <center>
                <a id="tabs">
                    <ul>

                        @if (Model != null) { 
                            if (Model.cantidadMensajes >= 5)
                            {
                                for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
                                {
                                    <li><a href="#tabs-@i"> @i</a></li>
                                }
                            }
                            else { 
                                for (var i = 1; i <= Model.cantidadMensajes; i++)
                                {
                                    <li><a href="#tabs-@i"> @i</a></li>
                                }                
                            }
                        }

                    </ul>
                    @previsualizaciones
                </div>

                        <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellspacing="4">

                            <tr>
                                <td width="36%">Cantidad de mensajes</td>
                                <td width="44%">
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.cantidadMensajes, new { @id = "CantidadMensajes", @class = "input-login", @readonly = "readonly" })
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Cantidad de contactos</td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.cantidadContactos, new { @id = "CantidadContactos", @class = "input-login", @readonly = "readonly" })
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Saldo</td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.saldo, new { @id = "Saldo", @class = "input-login", @readonly = "readonly" })
                                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.idTransaccion, new { @id = "idTransaccion" })
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        </table>
            </center><br>
            <center>
                <table width="122" border="0" align="center" cellspacing="10">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="51"><a onclick="EnviarMensajes()" class="boton-para-enviar" style="margin:auto">Aprobar</a></td>
                        <td width="37"><a href="#" class="boton-para-NO-enviar" style="margin:auto">Rechazar</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </center>
            <br>
            <strong>Nota:</strong> Si el saldo no se encuentra completo para la cantidad total de mensajes, los mensajes que queden pendientes se enviarán cuando realice la recarga.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Check the controller out:

```
public ActionResult EnviarMensajeIndividual(MensajesEntity model)
        {
            InformacionEntity Info = new InformacionEntity();
            Info.error = false;
            model.usuarioCreacion = User.Identity.Name;

            if (HttpContext.Session["Lista"] != null && model.mensaje != null)
            {
                List<ContactoEntity> lista = HttpContext.Session["Lista"] as List<ContactoEntity>;

                int idTransaccion = mdm.EnviarMensajes(model, lista, 1);
                if (idTransaccion > 0)
                {
                    Info = mdm.InformacionDeEnvio(idTransaccion);
                    Info.error = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    //error
                    Info.error = true;
                    Info.mensajeError = "error.";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // tiene q tener contactos agregados
                Info.error = true;
                Info.mensajeError = "error";
            }
            var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var Data = new ContentResult();
            js.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
            Data.Content = js.Serialize(Info);
            Data.ContentType = "application/json";

            return Data;
        }
```

Comment: might be related :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23293886/mvc-uppercase-model-vs-lowercase-model

Comment: You don't need to use the `@` symbol before `Model` if the `@` symbol is before the `if` statement.

Comment: I already removed the @ symbol, but with no luck.

Comment: @AlejandroSanchez show us an update of what you did.. update your question please

Comment: I just update it. Check it out, please. @BviLLe_Kid

Comment: Okay, and you still can't access properties?  Or are the properties null?

Comment: @AlejandroSanchez Can you show us the controller Action that passes the InformacionEntity object to the View?

Comment: The properties are null, I can't get into  @if (Model != null) { } because model is always null When I use Model.anyProperty.

Comment: @AlejandroSanchez Okay then you need to post your controller code for this action.

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid. Done, The controller was added. Please let me know if you need something else

Comment: Since your view has this at the top.. `@model SeaConnectionManager.Modelos.EnvioMensajes.InformacionEntity`.. it is expecting an object of type `InformacionEntity`.. so you have to give it that object.. which in your controller is `InformacionEntity Info = new InformacionEntity();`.. so `return View(Info);`

Comment: The action you posted doesn't even return a view, so it's obviously not the right one if you're getting far enough to see that `Model` is null in your view.

Comment: Attributes are not properties.  Please don't confuse the two.

Comment: I am very new working with ASP.NET C#, sorry for confusing you. @BviLLe_Kid, you were just right! Thank you.!

Comment: @AlejandroSanchez I posted an answer. Please mark this as accepted so that this question can be seen as answered.

Comment: The controller action you have posted is the Get action ? You want the data to be passed from there to the view?

Comment: @AlejandroSanchez Are you calling this controller action via AJAX ? I have posted an answer below. Please try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your Model is being given the value of null is because at the top of your view you have this:

`@model SeaConnectionManager.Modelos.EnvioMensajes.InformacionEntity‌​`

So, your view is **expecting** an object of type `InformacionEntity`.

However in your controller where you are supposed to be returning that object to the view, you are not returning an `InformacionEntity` object.

So in your controller, you have this:

`InformacionEntity Info = new InformacionEntity();`

Which is what you need to return.

So change your return statement to:

`return View(Info);`

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Thank you! It helps me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Remove @ from Model

```
@if (Model != null) { 
                        if (Model.cantidadMensajes >= 5)
                        {
                            for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
                            {
                                <li><a href="#tabs-@i"> @i</a></li>
                            }
                        }
                        else { 
                            for (var i = 1; i <= Model.cantidadMensajes; i++)
                            {
                                <li><a href="#tabs-@i"> i</a></li>
                            }                
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I tryied it but with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Model type of your view is SeaConnectionManager.Modelos.EnvioMensajes.InformacionEntity‌​

That means the view should be rendered with an object of that type.

The controller action of yours show that you are not returning the view at all. Instead you are returning ContentResult. The content result can not be translated to the model type expected by the view. That's why your model is always null and you are not getting inside the block "if (Model != null)".

You need to make following changes to the controller action.

```
public ActionResult EnviarMensajeIndividual(MensajesEntity model)
    {
        InformacionEntity Info = new InformacionEntity();
        Info.error = false;
        model.usuarioCreacion = User.Identity.Name;

        if (HttpContext.Session["Lista"] != null && model.mensaje != null)
        {
            List<ContactoEntity> lista = HttpContext.Session["Lista"] as List<ContactoEntity>;

            int idTransaccion = mdm.EnviarMensajes(model, lista, 1);
            if (idTransaccion > 0)
            {
                Info = mdm.InformacionDeEnvio(idTransaccion);
                Info.error = false;
            }
            else
            {
                //error
                Info.error = true;
                Info.mensajeError = "error.";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // tiene q tener contactos agregados
            Info.error = true;
            Info.mensajeError = "error";
        }
        return View(Info);

    }
```

Here I am assuming that the name of your view is the same as the name of your action.